# What if black holes consumed exotic matter?

Tags: black-holes, exotic-matter

I've just watched Kurzgesagt in a Nutshell and I've been thinking of exotic matter for a while. What if black holes tried to consume exotic matter?

Comment: There are various kinds of [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter). Without more specificity, this question is too vague to be answered.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please do not assume that readers have watched what you have watched.